# How to check if two contours match using OpenCV matchShapes?

Tags: java, scala, opencv

I am trying to check if the contours detected in two images match. I've seen that OpenCV has a function called `matchShapes` which returns a metric of similarity. However, it receives just a `Mat` of `Points`, not all of them. In the [doc example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#contours-more-functions), it passes to the method the first Mat Of Points.

So, I can run this method passing one Mat Of Points and getting a metric each time, but how can I do it if I want a unique similarity metric?

Maybe iterating over all Mat Of Points, aplying `matchShapes` and computing a mean later?

The code:

```
var Binarized1:Mat=new Mat()
var Binarized2:Mat=new Mat()
var contours1 = new util.ArrayList[MatOfPoint]()
var contours2 = new util.ArrayList[MatOfPoint]()

//computing thresholds
 org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.threshold(mole1,Binarized1,0,255,org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV+org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU)
 org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.threshold(mole2,Binarized2,0,255,org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV+org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU)

//finding contours
 org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.findContours(Binarized1,contours1,new Mat(),org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
 org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.findContours(Binarized2,contours2,new Mat(),org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

//matching shapes
 var cnt1=contours1.get(0)
 var cnt2=contours2.get(0)
 print("matching shapes="+ org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.matchShapes(cnt1,cnt2,org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1,0))
```

I know there are similar questions posted, but no one does the trick for me.

Comment: You should see for `contour Moments`, using which  you may define your own metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple contours in both images, then you need to match them first, before evaluating for an overall similarity.

Imagine you have one square and one disc in both images. You will have two contours in each, but you first need to match disc contour to disc contour and square contour to square contour. You can do that by an n*m comparison of contours, and storing the correspondences per contour.

Afterwards, you can define a similarity metric of images, which is the mean of matching scores per matched contours.